# Chosen.js select drop-down falling below view window, becoming nearly unusable

Tags: html, layout, jquery-chosen

In edge cases my select box options drop out of view and can not be scrolled/seen.

Desired outcome(s):

- A smarter drop down/up behavior for chosen.js select that makes the optimal decision for viewing the most options at once.

-and/or-

- A baseplate that truly stays fixed to the bottom of the screen.  It starts there and stays there, and, as the page contents outgrow the window, the contents of the window rise out of view instead of descend out of view.  With this I could make the baseplate high enough to act as a buffer to keep the select from getting too close to the edge of the viewing window for at least a partial scroll becoming inaccessible.  I'm using a header/article/footer model I found on w3schools, but I don't understand it well.

New lines containing select are dynamically added to the DOM by the user in this application, and when the contents fill up the available browser height the edge case appears. I'm using chosen.js with being able to type in a search for a possible option match.  I can type in a search, but don't know if I hit a match until I hit enter. If I didn't know what the options were already, selecting something would be  impossible.  Without chosen.js, the select box behavior is to start dropping up when it would run out of room dropping down.  I'm guessing either:

- chosen.js is incapable of dropping up
- the decision to drop up/down does not take into account added dimensions introduced by chosen's search features.

I tried a number of different code playgrounds to provide a sample to work with, but I can't find one that will recognize chosen.js  This shows acceptable behavior through non-chosen select:

https://jsfiddle.net/f4L27u9g/#&togetherjs=teea1GGbe7

[Minus a solution, if you can direct me towards providing a chosen-enabled sample that would be helpful]

```
<Html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
          function addTransaction(){
             $('<Select>')
               .attr('class', 'chosen-select')
               .attr('style', 'width:150px;')
               .appendTo($('#myForm'));

             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));
             $('<option>').text('sample').appendTo($('.chosen-select'));

             $('<br>').appendTo($('#myForm'));

             $(".chosen-select").chosen({});
             $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
         }
    </script>
    <style>
            * {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
              position: relative;
              padding: 1em;
            }
            header {
              position: relative;
              background-color: #665;
              padding: 10px;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 35px;
              color: white;
            }
            article {
              position: relative;
              padding: 20px;
              background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
            footer {
              background-color: #777;
              padding: 5px;
              text-align: center;
              color: white;
              position: absolute;
              right: 0;bottom:0;left:0;
            }
            section:after {
              content: "";
              display: table;
              clear: both;
            }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      random header
    </header>

    <article>
      random article
      <Form id="myForm" action="#" method="post"></Form>
        </article>      

    <footer class="footer">
                <Form id="addTransactions" style="float:left">
                    <button class="addNewTransaction" id="addNewTransaction" type="button" onclick="addTransaction()">Add</button>              
                </Form>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it and it was "dropping up" as it was supposed to.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle does.  I couldn't get the fiddle (or codepen, etc.) to run chosen's version of select, so the fiddle represents a desired case.